# Brand Links as a Subdomain

Tags: url-rewrite

I have a link about Acana. Link is listing all Acana branded products. Here it is; https://www.solempet.com/acana

I want to change it to acana.solempet.com for seo reasons.

How can i do this? I couldn't find any guides for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as we know you can't due to Magento redirecting to base url. We have this ourselves but it's part of a complete architecture so wouldn't work for you.

Answer (score 1):

Simplest solution is to create a store for this brand.
Then you can set a separate url through settings / configuration / web / base url.

Or build a reverse proxy acana.solempet.com -> www.solempet.com/acana (which of coarse leads to some other challenges)